# removing page numbering in a specific page but continuing page numbering onwards

Tags: page-breaking

I am using report file for my thesis. Before each chapter begins, I want to use a page containing the following in the middle without page numbering, but page number should  continued in the next page. Similarly, for each chapters.

CHAPTER i
INTRODUCTION

Comment: Did you try something like `\clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}[code for your text]` (or `\cleardoublepage &c.`)?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to combine packages `fancyhdr` and `titlesec`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum,titlesec,fancyhdr}

% Redefine the plain page style, which is used for the chapter page
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Line at the header invisible
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% Line at the footer invisible
}

% use titlesec to adjust the chapter page layout and insert a \clearpage
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%  remove [display] to get everything on the same line
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Large}% 
% change \Large to \LARGE or whatever you prefer
[\clearpage\ignorespaces]%

\begin{document}
\chapter{Another day in paradise}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}‎
```